# how to install caldecott on win 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created an and I want to upload that on phpfog but I am getting trouble while uploading my database here on the first step, I have win 7 x64 , I downloaded and installed command prompt with ruby, while creating a tunnel :

```
 C:\Ruby200\devkit>gem install caldecott --platform=ruby
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

    make
    generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
    compiling generator.c
    generator.c: In function 'cState_aref':
    generator.c:632:5: warning: variable 'state' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-
    variable]
    generator.c: In function 'isArrayOrObject':
    generator.c:867:5: warning: suggest parentheses around '&&' within '||' [-Wparen
    theses]
    linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so

    make install
    /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jso
    n-1.6.8/ext/json/ext/json/ext
    /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gem
    s/json-1.6.8/ext/json/ext/json/ext': No such file or directory
    make: *** [install-so] Error 1


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.
    8 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.6.8/ext/json/ext/ge
    nerator/gem_make.out

    C:\Ruby200\devkit>gem install caldecott --platform=ruby


`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Win7 x64, Ruby 2.0.0, DevKit (DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151)

I faced the same issue. My solution:

1. Download gem source from github - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/caldecott/archive/master.zip
2. Unzip to C:\caldecott (for example)
3. Open file caldecott.gemspec and change version of json dependency to "~> 1.7"
4. Open command prompt, move to gem source directory and perfrom:

   gem build caldecott.gemspec

   gem install caldecott-0.0.5.gem

That's all

Comment: What do u mean by `4. Open command prompt, move to gem source directory and perfrom:`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs with Ruby 2.0.0 version. Downgrade to Ruby 1.9.3